# Redux reducer - a single state object or multiple states?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider these two patterns for reducer's state:

1. A single state object:

```
// personReducer.js
const initialState = {
  personInfo: {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    foo: "",
    bar: "",
    baz: "",
    foo1: "",
    bar1: "",
    bar2: "",
    foo2: "",
    foo3: "",
  }
  // some not-to-mention states
};
```

2. Multiple states (without the `person` level):

```
// personReducer.js
const initialState = {
  firstName: "", // no person level
  lastName: "",
  foo: "",
  bar: "",
  baz: "",
  foo1: "",
  bar1: "",
  bar2: "",
  foo2: "",
  foo3: ""
};
```

Which one is better? What confuses me is:

```
// Person.jsx - pattern 1
const mapStateToProps = ({ personInfo }) => {
 personInfo
}

// Person.jsx - pattern 2
const mapStateToProps = ({ firstName, lastName }) => {
 firstName,
 lastName
}

// Human.jsx - pattern 1
const mapStateToProps = ({ personInfo }) => {
 personInfo
}

// Human.jsx - pattern 2
const mapStateToProps = ({ foo, bar }) => {
 foo,
 bar
}
```

Let's say we have 2 components `Person` and `Human` in our app, both of them will connect to `personReducer` to retrieve personal information.

For pattern 1:

In `Person` component, I dispatch an action to update `firstName` inside `personInfo`, which later will force `Human` to re-render as well, does it? Something like this in our reducer:

```
case UPDATE_PERSON_INFO: {
 return {
  ...state,
  personInfo: {
    ...state.personInfo,
    firstName: payload.firstName
  }
 }
}
```

For pattern 2:

In `Person` component, I dispatch an action to update `firstName`, which later will not force `Human` to re-render, because `Human` is not mapping `firstName` to its props, but `foo, bar`. Am I right? Something
like:

```
case UPDATE_PERSON_INFO: {
 return {
  ...state,
  firstName: payload.firstName  
 }
}
```

Comment: You can have a personInfo reducer and use [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) for mapState I advice using [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) and compose selectPersonInfo, [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) are some examples of how to use reselect with react-redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will re-render in both cases because in both patterns you update the reference to the new immutable state object.

If you want to prevent unnecessary renderings of components you have to use memoized selectors in `mapStateToProps`. Here is the [documentation link](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) and [GitHub](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

These, selectors should be specific for your components.